# sftp first connection before exchange cert

Tags: certificates, sftp

If a client connects for the first time to a server via SFTP, the first connection before receiving the server certificate is transmitted in the clear?Let me explain: it is assumed that the client wants to connect for the first time to the SFTP server, before receiving the certificate, it will send its credentials in the clear? This is the only time where the user And password are send in clear?

Comment: The password is never sent in the clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFTP is an [extension of SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). The [SSH protocol supports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell):

> There are several ways to use SSH; one is to use automatically generated public-private key pairs to simply encrypt a network connection, and then use password authentication to log on.

That is, the secure connection is created before authentication occurs. In short, username and password are never sent in the clear.

Comment: And on most systems there are no certificates at all. The server publickey is manually verified and then remembered (unless someone clobbers known_hosts etc) and if client auth uses publickey, which is one option, it must be preconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP is a subsystem of the SSH protocol. The SSH protocol session comprises several "moments", the key-exchange (or KEX) being the first one.

So your SFTP client will:

- connect to the SSH server
- perform the key exchange and instantiate session encryption (**from this moment on, the session is secure**)
- send an authentication request which only contains the username
- receive from the server a response that states which authentication types/methods are available for that particular username (password, PKI, ...)
- request to perform one of the authentications in the list returned by the server
- receive authorization from the server to continue with the requested authentication type
- send the authentication data (a password if password-auth was chosen, a public key if PKI-auth was chosen, and so on...)
- receive a response from the server (authorized, rejected, or need further auth)
- if authorized, then and only then request the opening of the SFTP subsystem

As you can see - your username and password are never sent in clear. And actually the password may never be sent at all, in case your client performs a different type of authentication, like PKI auth for example.

Comment: I'm not sure this adds anything to the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't know, I thought the accepted answer was lacking a lot of detail. Kind of like "trust me, it works". I thought that explaining HOW it works would be better, and give more peace of mind to the requester.

Comment: I think this answer would be stronger if you included reference(s).